# Paralel port read/write C# Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, com

I want to be able to read and write to an LPT port from C#.

Tried to import inpoutx64.dll and inpout32.dll, to use these to read and write to the LPT port. But I get the following error message when I add the reference ...

> A reference to 'C:\Users\User\Documents\inpoutx64.dll' could
>   not be added. Please ensure that the file is accessible, and that it
>   is a valid assembly or COM component.

Is there any other DLLer for windows 10, or is there anything i can use in Windows SDK to communicate with the LCP port ...?

I use Windows 10 64 bit, and .NET 4.5.

Comment: Is inpoutx64.dll in C:\Users\User\Documents ? If you can find the dll, then copy it there. Have you compiled your code as 64bit? If not change the target platform in the project properties.

Comment: Hello, maybe I also have to use a parallel port (a parallel port on a PCI Express card) in a Windows 10 64-bit computer. In your case have you also used a PCI express card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `inpoutx64.dll` and `inpout32.dll` are no valid assembly or COM components you can't import them using the project references.

You need to import the functions of the  dll in code like

```
[DllImport("inpout32.dll", EntryPoint = "Inp32")]
private static extern int Input(int adress);

[DllImport("inpout32.dll", EntryPoint = "Out32")]
private static extern void Output(int adress, int value);
```

You can find a great description and more information about this *import* at [this article](https://drthitirat.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/combine-gui-of-c-with-c-codes/).

Note that the dll needs to be in the same folder as your executable. This is easily possible by adding the dll to your project and set the build action to *copy to output directory*.

Comment: An error occured:\nUnable to load DLL 'inpout32.dll': Den angitte modulen ble ikke funnet. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
 I have copy the dll to the root of my project , do I also need to add them to system32 ?

Comment: No, do not add it to the system32. Just add the file to your project and set the correct build action like shown in this picture: http://www.sparsity-technologies.com/StartingGuide/imgs/Figure-15.png

Comment: Thx :)that worked :) !! 
Maybe a little off topic, but how can I sniff traffic from output without events? Do a loop and read output?